# How to refresh the windows desktop programmatically (i.e. F5) from C#?

Tags: c#, .net

Yeah, I know this seems like a dumb question, its just a one-off hack I need to wrap up a somewhat mundane task so I can move on to something more interesting.

EDIT:
Maybe more info would help: I'm trying to remove some shortcuts from the desktop and I need the user to see it removed right away (so they don't have to press F5).

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can use the [SHChangeNotify](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762118(v=vs.85).aspx) API.

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("Shell32.dll")]
private static extern int SHChangeNotify(int eventId, int flags, IntPtr item1, IntPtr item2);
```

and then call it this way

```
SHChangeNotify(0x8000000, 0x1000, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
```

Comment: @DSO How did you "Cut" it?

Comment: Any idea what the reason is behind having to pass `SHCNE_ASSOCCHANGED (0x8000000)` as `eventId`?

Comment: I'm using Squirrel installer and removing two icons. What I'm seeing using this method is that it's unreliable - sometimes works, sometimes not. I've tried adding in a delay (1.5s) and that helps but it still fails.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're looking for [IActiveDesktop::ApplyChanges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776346(VS.85).aspx). You will need to access this via the COM interface, which should be fairly easy with all the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645736(VS.71).aspx) Microsoft provides on COM Interop.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, looks like that this would probably work... however the Win32 approach from Tom was a bit easier to use right away.