# Update folder icon through SHChangeNotify API

Tags: c#, shell32.dll, desktop.ini

I have problem refreshing the custom icon which i have set in desktop.ini. 
I referred many post in SO and codeproject but still i am facing this issue my prograt sets everything icon path, confirmOp, icon index, making it hidden and system attribute but still it doesn't get refreshed immediately. So i reviewed some post saying that it can be done through SHChangeNotify API and in that i found out SHCNE_UPDATEDIR.

So can someone please help me out with this. I would really appreciate for it.

Comment: Are you asking how to use it? http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/shell32.shchangenotify

Comment: Hello Alex, I tried that but still no luck.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/647286/3195477