# Notify Windows 10 of start menu changes

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0, windows-10

I have an app that sometimes dynamically adds and removes entries from the start menu (and the Desktop), by placing shortcuts (created with `WshShellClass`) in the start menu folder (`Environment.SpecialFolder.StartMenu`). If any such changes occur, I already notify the shell of changes using `SHChangeNotify`, as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/647286/1600). Specifically:

```
    private static void _RefreshWindowsDesktop()
    {
        // http://stackoverflow.com/a/647286/1600

        NativeMethods.SHChangeNotify(NativeMethods.HChangeNotifyEventID.SHCNE_ASSOCCHANGED,
                                     NativeMethods.HChangeNotifyFlags.SHCNF_FLUSH,
                                     IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
    }
```

However, on Windows 10, Start Menu search frequently breaks (I've never seen this behavior in Windows Vista or 7), where a new shortcut often *doesn't* show up for days, and in turn, an old shortcut that has been deleted days ago still shows up as a "search result". This is presumably due to changes to make modern apps appear in the Start Menu alongside classic desktop apps, but I'm not sure; online guides to that effect frankly strike me as voodoo.

Worse, when invoking that shortcut, Windows 10 just does *nothing* — there's no error indicating that the shortcut points nowhere (because it doesn't exist), nor does Windows learn and remove it afterwards.

So, my hope is there's a method akin `SHChangeNotify` to explicitly tell Windows 10 to invalidate or rebuild its Start Menu cache, such as asking it to reindex that particular folder, or telling it to manually add/remove an item from the index.

My app is WPF, but if a native method exists, I can detect the OS version and then conditionally invoke it. (Or even write an external Windows 10-specific UWP background app to launch if needed.)

Comment: There are user specific start menu/desktop and common for all users. Do you handle this correctly? E.g. what if you trying to delete item from local user menu item, while it's in common?

Comment: These short cuts are all user-specific and placed in the user profile's Start Menu directory, so that shouldn't be a problem.